# How to solve problem 'Blocked by Play Protect'

Tags: android, url, google-play

What to do to fix the problem in the photo below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtYtC.jpg)

This is the URL I send to Google.

> https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1vm286JK1mmbN-igPwzIOU7mKKsJ8eEdi

**I have filled out this form as shown below**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX0p0.png)

But after filling out this form, the email that Google sends me is as pictured below and I've tested several other URLs but it sends me the same error every time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq35H.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue happend to me. You have many choices:

**Solution 1:** If you disable Play Protect (Setting -> Google -> Security -> Google Play Protect -> Disable “Scan device for security threats”), the installation does go through without a problem.

I suspect this is the default Play Protect behaviour: Play Protect will show a popup warning upon first installtion of suspicious APK, after which it will block the installation without further warnings.

**Solution 2:** I created a new Key Store, set it to 50 years and filled up all the available fields. The newly signed APK doesn’t get flagged as suspicious google play protect.

**Solution 3:** Some mentioned the [Play Protect Appeals](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals), but I didn’t try this.

**Solution 4:** Publish your app to Play store.

Comment: About Solution 2, Have you installed the app even after 3 days? Because he gives this message again

Comment: If you want your users keep safe and didnt worry about that issue, try solution 4. Trust me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to avoid **PlayProtect** nowadays.

**Option-1**:
You have to upload your application in **Play Store**. Then Google manage it.

**Option-2**:
You have to disable the **PlayProtect** from **Play Store** application, but that's not ***recommended*** at all.

To disable follow below steps:

1. On your Android phone or tablet, open the **Google Play Store** app.
2. Tap Menu 》 PlayProtect 》 Settings.
3. Turn **Scan device for security threats** off.

Comment: What is the problem with the way I did it now?

Comment: No Problem from your side. It's a Google Play Store security feature to ensure more security to end user